# Convert Dictionary<string,List<foo>> to List<foo> in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Is there any other way to get `List<foo>` directly from ValueCollection.

Current I am using below code

```
 Dictionary<string,List<foo>> dic;

 List<foo> list= new List<foo>();

 foreach (List<foo> var in dic.Values)
 {               
      list.AddRange(var);
 }
```

OR

```
List<List<foo>> list= new List<List<foo>>(dic.Values);
```

Above conversion gives me `List<List<foo>` but  I want `List<foo>` from dic.values without using for each loop if possible using .NET 2.0.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a foreach loop?

Comment: Without Linq (.NET 3.5), you're going to need a `for` or `foreach` loop somewhere.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you may be able to *link* to .NET 3.0/3.5, yet still compile on an older version of visual studio.  The syntax wouldn't look as sexy, because you would have to access extension methods via static syntax, but it would at least be an alternative.

Comment: @Greg, it is possible to do without a for or foreach loop by implementing your own class for it.

Comment: @tster - Then the loop is in a custom class or a custom method. As I said, you will still have to write a loop *somewhere* - unless you use recursion or some other acrobatic feat to avoid it. Just use a `foreach` loop in-place or in a utility/extension method and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Without using LINQ or .NET 3.5, I don't know of any way to do this without some kind of `for` loop.  Even with LINQ, somewhere in the framework a `foreach` would be doing the same thing.

If you're chained to .NET 2.0 but have access to a later C# compiler version, you can use LinqBridge.dll to achieve the same effects - read about it [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx).  Note that this would require at least VS 2008 (targeting the 2.0 framework).  If you can use that, then all you'd have to do is

```
using System.Linq;

...

dic.Values.SelectMany(v => v).ToList();
```

Comment: LINQ would at least push the foreach out to iteration time instead of creation time.

Comment: True - and I suspect that the real win is that OP wouldn't have to write it themselves!  With LinqBridge, it would be possible with the 2.0 Framework, too.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the easy LINQ solution (not available in .NET 2.0)

```
dic.Values.SelectMany(list => list).ToList()
```

If you don't need a List and are OK with an IEnumerable then leave off the ToList()

The harder solution:

1. Define a class which implements IList and which has a constructor which takes a ValueCollection or ICollection
2. Implement all the methods on that.  you can keep track of all the list of T's and the index of the current list you are working on.

use

```
return new MyListCombiner<foo>(dict.Values);
```

Comment: The OP specifically mentions .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Don Kirby: Title says C# 2.0. Never mind, I don't mean to nitpick.

Comment: @Don Kirkby, I read "if possible" as referring to the use of a foreach loop, but it isn't completely clear.

Comment: I think you're right, @adrift, I probably misinterpreted that.

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach loop should be

```
Dictionary<string,List<foo>> dic;

 List<foo> list= new List<foo>();

 foreach (List<foo> var in dic.Values)
 {    
      foreach(foo bar in var){           
          list.AddRange(bar);
      }
 }
```

You were adding each list to a list, when you wanted to be adding each item of each list to a list.

And totally missed the for each loop part in your question.

I don't think that's possible in C# 2.0. LINQ is at heart just doing iterations over an `IEnumerable` which is all the foreach is doing

Comment: According to this reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx `AddRange` adds elements of a collection passed to it as `IEnumerable<T>`, to the list, so the OP's code is correct

Comment: @Maciej Hehl this is true, now I want to play with this to see why it isn't doing what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, any method you choose is going to involve a for-loop at some level of abstraction.  If you're staying in pure .NET 2.0, you'll have to write that for loop somewhere in your code.  This sort of data conglomeration is one of the main purposes of LINQ.  See the `SelectMany` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx

Depending on your requirements, you may be able to link to .NET 3.0/3.5, yet still compile on an older version of the toolset.  You'd still have to have 3.0/3.5 on the box you are running the application on, but wouldn't have to upgrade your tools.  The syntax also wouldn't look as sexy, because you would have to access extension methods via static method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 2.0 you must use either a loop, or [Poor Man's LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linq2005.aspx), with code that looks like this:

```
Linq(dic.Values).SelectMany(delegate(List<foo> list) { return list; }).ToList()
```

Where you define Linq() as

```
static PoorMansLinq<T> Linq<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new PoorMansLinq<T>(source);
}
```

I noticed that the first line doesn't currently work and I submitted an update to fix it. In the meantime, you can use the following as a workaround:

```
Linq(Linq(dic.Values).SelectMany(delegate(List<foo> list) { return list; })).ToList()
```

You could also use [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx), and call Enumerable directly, but this is cumbersome without C# 3.0.